# NetBeans and Mercurial - moving/deleting files and folders

Tags: version-control, netbeans, mercurial

I'm wondering if when using NetBeans and its Mercurial plugin I can only move/delete files/folders through the project navigator or I can change the project structure through the file explorer (Finder) and edit files using other editors then push the changes through NetBeans without issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit files with other editors. If you add, delete, or rename files from outside Netbeans I think you have to run `hg addremove`, I don't think it can be done inside Netbeans. See `hg help addremove` for more information on what it does. To track renames people often recommend to use the similarity option with 90 as argument.

See also [Netbeans Mercurial plugin doesn't have addremove option in GUI menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626942/netbeans-mercurial-plugin-doesnt-have-addremove-option-in-gui-menus)